# Connection Oracle database to Xampp

Tags: php, oracle, xampp

I also have a normal oracle 11.2.0 client installed (PATH and ORACLE_HOME are set correctly). I remove `;` on my `extension` on file `php.ini`. 
Now, I tried to connect, so i create a file with this code:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Oracle demo</title></head>
  <body>
  <?php 
    $conn=oci_connect("myuser","mypass","localhost/orc1");
    If (!$conn)
      echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
    else
      echo 'Succesfully connected with Oracle DB';

   oci_close($conn);
   ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

That file is in folder "test" in "htdocs".
When i put that url: http://localhost/test/scriptdemo.php
shows me that error:

```
Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12541: TNS:no listener in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\scriptdemo.php on line 5
Failed to connect to Oracle
```

I have the same password and username that i use in Oracle. Thank's

Comment: Was your Oracle database server up and running?

Comment: @PeterM yes .. I have a connection on SQL Oracle and it´s runnign ok

Comment: Start by changing around the connection string (3rd parameter) of the call to see if it fixes things. http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php -- From the documentation:  "connection_string    Contains the Oracle instance to connect to. It can be an » Easy Connect string, or a Connect Name from the tnsnames.ora file, or the name of a local Oracle instance. "

Comment: Try it with the // prefix in the easy connect string syntax described in that link. And alternatively, try with the connect name as defined in tnsnames.ora